# How to group by using multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table

```
Type    SubType value
A      1       1
A      2       2
A      3       3
A      4       4
B      1       1
B      2       2
B      3       3
C      1       1
C      2       2
C      3       3
C      4       4
```

I want to group by all rows except where Type=A and the output should like below

```
Type    Sum
A1    1
A2    2
A3    3 
A4    4
B     6
C     10
```

Is it possible to group by few rows on one condition and others on a different condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have to write an expression that creates the group definition:

```
Select case When Type = 'A' then type + ltrim(str(subtype, 9))
            Else Type End Type, Sum(Value) Sum
From table
Group By case When Type = 'A' then type + ltrim(str(subtype, 9))
            Else Type End
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can `GROUP BY` a `CASE` expression;

```
SELECT CASE WHEN type='A' 
            THEN type+CAST(subtype AS VARCHAR(MAX))
            ELSE type END [Type],
       SUM(value) [Sum]
FROM mytable
GROUP BY CASE WHEN type='A'
              THEN type+CAST(subtype AS VARCHAR(MAX))
              ELSE type END
ORDER BY [Type]
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c4ab/5).

In SQL Server 2012, you can use `CONCAT` without the cast, which simplifies the query somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

Another option. Split the logic into the 2 cases:

```
SELECT Type + CAST(subtype AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Type,
       SUM(Value) AS Sum
FROM mytable
WHERE Type = 'A'
GROUP BY Type, Subtype

UNION ALL

SELECT Type,
       SUM(Value)
FROM mytable
WHERE Type <> 'A'
GROUP BY Type

ORDER BY Type ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6c4ab/8)** (thnx to [@Joachim Isakkson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23459170/how-to-group-by-using-multiple-conditions/23459260#23459260))